# When do we need to use Class component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I came to realised that hooks on functional components could do what class component could do without the class component lifecycle.

Is there any example where we need to and have to use a class component instead of a functional component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ErrorBoundaries can only be implemented with class components.

As per the [hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes)

> There are no Hook equivalents to the uncommon
>   `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`, `getDerivedStateFromError` and
>   `componentDidCatch` lifecycles yet.

In order to use the above lifecycles you would need to use class components

Apart from this all other useCases can be implemented with functional components with hooks

Comment: `all other useCases` - deliberate pun?

Comment: @SteveGreatrex completely unintentional. Probably a habit of writing hooks :-)